# Ajax request to Jetty server on same node

Tags: ajax, jetty, same-origin-policy

I want to use html/js as the graphical interface for my Java apps, and for this I have a Jetty http server running on port `8040`.

The client scripting is done on a Mongoose server on port `8080`, using the jQuery AJAX `get()` method.

When performing the AJAX request, I get the

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8040/. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not  allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I did a bit a google:ing and found that this is known as the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), and if I understand this right, the script can not make a request to another port on the same adress? So how do I make this work, ie. run both the java server and the javascript client on the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this wiki page:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter

Comment: Actually, only one line of code needed to be added to the Jetty HelloWorld example to make this work: `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`. This led me in the right direction though.